# CGrigCtrl horizontal scrolling

Tags: c++, mfc

How to enable horizontal scrollbar smooth scrolling for CGridCtrl. Now it jumps by fields when I scroll it from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about CGridCtrl published in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx) CodeProject article.

If so, then you're going to have to completely override the drawing methods to offset the columns by the current scroll position (instead of calculating the first column to display from the scroll position).

To get you started, you should begin by looking at [`GetScrollPos(SB_HORZ)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz2w3ccs%28VS.80%29.aspx) to use as an offset to begin drawing.

Comment: Thanks, I`ll try. One more question: what method should I override? "void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)" or something else?